# Удалить символ в промежутке между символами

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Представим ситуацию, что у нас есть CSS стиль.

```
body {
  margin: 0;

  background: blue;



  position: relative;
}
```

Как записать регулярное выражение, чтобы оно "прошло" внутри фигурных скобок (`{...}`) и удалила оттуда лишние символы "новой строки" (`\n{2,}`), чтобы в результате получилось следующее:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: а данном конкретном случае `\n+` можно заменить на `\n`

Comment: Если нет вложенных фигурных скобок, `.replace(/{[^{}]+}/g, function(x) {return x.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '');})`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, оформите комментарий как ответ, отмечу его как верный

Comment: Да, только надо заменить на `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только если внутри фигурных скобок нет вложенных фигурных скобок, можно использовать

```
.replace(/{[^{}]+}/g, function(x) {return x.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '\n');})
```

Пример работы кода:

```js
var text = "body {\n  margin: 0;\n\n  background: blue;\n\n\n\n  position: relative;\n}";
console.log( text.replace(/{[^{}]+}/g, function(x) {return x.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '\n');}) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(`body {
  margin: 0;

  background: blue;

     

  position: relative;
}`.replace(/(\r?\n)(((?!\r|\n)\s)*\r?\n)*/g, "$1"))
```

Comment: В данном ответе нет проверки на местонахождение совпадения между определёнными символами. См. требования *чтобы оно "прошло" внутри фигурных скобок (`{...}`)*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, но в вопросе в других местах переводов нет, а то, что больше нигде удалять не надо, не уточняется.